# How do I pass additional data to callback method in Laravel Socialite?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel Socialite for social authentication. It has two methods redirect() and callback. While redirection I want to pass some data to the callback method, but I am unable to get data there. I used sessions to put values but I am getting nothing in session in the callback method.

Callback method destroys all session data?

I am achieving like this,

```
public function redirect(Request $req)
{    
   session(['tenant_slug' => $req->TenantSlug]);
   return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
}
```

and in callback method,

```
public function callback(Request $req,$provider)
{ 
   dd(session()->all());        
   $getInfo = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
}
```

I am printing all session data but I am getting an empty sessions.

How do I achieve this?

Please help me with this.

Comment: why are you using the `stateless` method?

Comment: @lagbox I am doing it for mobile api's

Comment: well you can try passing extra data that will go with the redirect with the `with` method

Comment: @lagbox then It gives me error 'Call to a member function flash() on null'.

Comment: what are you calling that on?   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#optional-parameters ... haven't used socialite in a long time so not sure if these optional parameters get sent back to the callback but you can pass extra data when redirecting them away

Comment: @lagbox ok will check